# Recording Multi Channel Audio with Screen Capture

Tags: video, audio, sync

I wish to record 16 channels of analogue audio with 1 channel of video of desktop capture in perfect time sync.

I've tried using a CCTV DVR recording solution but the video proved too low quality for use however it did sync the audio and video perfectly.

I can't find a DAW with a simple video functionality or an video editor with multi channel audio functionality AND to make matters worse I can't find anything that will screen capture a desktop that will work with DAW/Video editors.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on how much money you're willing to drop.  Also, are looking to record the computer screen video while simultaneously recording the audio? or could you have an existing video track to then track audio to?

The last couple versions of ProTools support video in the multi-track audio process.  Also Sony's VegasPro line does audio and video together.  I gather that Ableton can also play with both.

Comment: As cheaply as possible to be honest. I was thinking along the lines of something like recording the screen with a program like Bondicam and then audio on Pro Tools/Nuendo with certain interfaces that amount to 24 inputs or possibly using something like an Alesis HD24 hard disk recorder and splitting one track into the machine recording the screen then lining up the audio tracks later.